# Remove XML node in Notepad++

Tags: xml, localization, notepad++, translation

I have a large XML with the structure below. Now, I want to get rid of the `<tuv xml:lang="en-GB"><seg>CONTENT</seg></tuv>` nodes, so for each unit only the de-DE part stays (`<tuv xml:lang="de-DE"><seg>CONTENT</seg></tuv>`). Is there a way to do this with Notepad++ or a different tool? I am not really into coding, so the simpler the better.

What I have:

```
<tu tuid="ID_0">
<tuv xml:lang="en-GB">
<seg>Hello!</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="de-DE">
<seg>Hallo!</seg>
</tuv>
</tu>
<tu tuid="ID_1">
<tuv xml:lang="en-GB">
<seg>This is a test content! :)</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="de-DE">
<seg>Das ist ein Testinhalt! :)</seg>
</tuv>
</tu>
<tu tuid="ID_2">
<tuv xml:lang="en-GB">
<seg>All your base are belong tu us ...</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="de-DE">
<seg>Och nö, echt jetzt?</seg>
</tuv>
</tu>
```

What I want:

```
<tu tuid="ID_0">
<tuv xml:lang="de-DE">
<seg>Hallo!</seg>
</tuv>
</tu>
<tu tuid="ID_1">
<tuv xml:lang="de-DE">
<seg>Das ist ein Testinhalt! :)</seg>
</tuv>
</tu>
<tu tuid="ID_2">
<tuv xml:lang="de-DE">
<seg>Och nö, echt jetzt?</seg>
</tuv>
</tu>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, AFAIK... would be best to move this question to `superuser.com` to get your answers.

Comment: I received a solution, if anyone is ever looking for this as well: Ctrl+H (Replace...)

Find what: <tuv xml:lang="en-GB">.*?</tuv>

Search mode: Regular expression

checked: . matches newline

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by Notepad++ regex find and search.
Hit <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**H**</kbd> to open Find/Replace dialog box

- Find What : `<tuv xml:lang="en-GB">\r\n.*\r\n.*\r\n`
- Replace With : (Leave It Blank)
- Search Mode: Regular expression
- Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>